# Jquery mobile conflicting Salesforce stylesheet

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, salesforce, visualforce, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to create a simple visualforce page with Jquery mobile but whenever I add Jquery mobile library in my VF page my standard Saleforce global search and stylesheet breaks.

In customer portal and Communities , same page will causse issues in Salesforce Case and Leads tabs as well.

My VF page -

```
<apex:page >

   <head>    
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.2/jquery.mobile-1.1.2.min.css" />
        <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryMobile, 'MobileJquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js')}" />
        <apex:styleSheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryMobile, 'MobileJquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css')}" /> 
        <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryMobile, 'MobileJquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js')}" /> 
  </head>
</apex:page>
```

can anyone please help me out on same?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce includes a lot of javascript libraries that also may use '$' symbol as a shortcut and this can cause all sorts of problems. There is a simple fix as we can give jQuery it’s own special name.

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```